# Unable to save a char array using fprintf()

Tags: arrays, char

I am unable to save a char array using fprint() and i cannot figure out why. The below codes compliles correctly but saves nothing to file. Please advise.

```
static char bitSpecial[100];

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

FILE *fp

fp = fopen(thefilename, "w+");
        if (fp == NULL) {           
            printf("I couldn't open file for writing.\n");
            exit(0);
        }       
/* populate bitSpecial one character at the time and verify array is full */

fprintf(fp,"%s", bitSpecial);

if (fclose(fp) != 0) puts("Unable to close the file");

return
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It'll be easier to identify the problem with the full code. I tried the following snippet and it worked:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

#include <string.h>  // for strerror
#include <errno.h>   // for errno

static char bitSpecial[100];

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
    char * thefilename = "test";
    FILE *fp;

    fp = fopen(thefilename, "w+");
    if (fp == NULL) {           
        printf("I couldn't open file for writing.\n");
        return 1;
    }   

    /* populate bitSpecial one character at the time and verify array is full */
    bitSpecial[0] = 'a';
    bitSpecial[1] = '\n';
    bitSpecial[2] = '\0'; // terminator

    if (fprintf(fp,"%s", bitSpecial) < 0)
        printf("[+] fprintf failed with '%s'\n", strerror(errno));

    if (fclose(fp) != 0) 
        puts("Unable to close the file");

    return 0;
}
```

Verify that you put a null terminator (`\0`) at the end of bitSpecial, and check the return value of `fprintf`.

Comment: Thank you - as expected your code complied beautifully which inspired me to start using putc() and uncovered another fatal error in my code. Thanks again!